# Redefine the bson tag in golang, how to be compatible with the fields in the database with lowercase field names?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

There are many structures(There are roughly hundreds of structures, all generated automatically by a tool.) like this:

```
type ChatInfo struct {
    Name         string `json:"name"`
    IconFrame    uint64 `json:"iconFrame"`
}
```

The bson tag was forgotten, causing the field name in the database to become lowercase.
Like this:

```
{
    "name" : "myname",
    "iconframe" :101
}
```

---

Now, I want to add the bson tag:

```
type ChatInfo struct {
    Name         string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    IconFrame    uint64 `json:"iconFrame" bson:"iconFrame"`
}
```

But when I read the data from the database, I find that the value of the `IconFrame` field is 0.

I want to find a way to maintain compatibility with the original lowercase field names. Because there is a lot of data and the storage is somewhat disorganized, it is not very practical to modify the data in the database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement custom BSON unmarshaling logic that decodes both `iconframe` and `iconFrame` MongoDB fields into the `ChatInfo.IconFrame` field, but that custom logic would run in all document decoding!

You simply don't want that unnecessary overhead. Simplest is to rename existing fields in MongoDB. You just have to run a few update operations once, and then you'll be good to go forever.

For example, to rename the `iconframe` field to `iconFrame`, use this:

```
db.chatinfo.updateMany(
  {"iconframe": {$exists: true}},
  {$rename: {"iconframe": "iconFrame"}}
)
```

(The filter part may even by empty as non-existing fields will not be updated.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution provided, as I said before, there are many structures and the storage location is also messy, this method is not suitable for me. Thanks again.

Comment: I believe it can't be that complicated that it would take more time to write these renames than to implement the custom unmarshaling properly. You can only win on the long run. This is a situation where you can avoid punishing your future-self for your past "mistakes".